# change the color of the particular header on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My problem is when i mouse over the `fois` header its text doesn't changes to white color i don't know where i am wrong.or what to include.please help me........
another problem when the fois tab is active the color of the text appear as white

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <!--  <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="accord.js"></script>
        <style>
            .wrap {
                margin-left: 0px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                width: 100px;
            }

            .accordion1 {
                width: 178px;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                list-style: none;
                border: 1px solid #ddd;
            }

                .accordion1 h2 {
                    font-size: 12px;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    margin: 0px;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    padding: .25em .25em .25em 2em;
                    color: #333;
                    background: url('compo_images/gradient_v_gray.gif') repeat-x;
                    background: url("./compo_images/arrow_exp_s.gif") 1em .75em no-repeat;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }

                    .accordion1 h2:hover {
                        background: url('compo_images/gradient_v_orange.gif') repeat-x;
                        color: white;
                    }

                .accordion1 li div.content {
                    padding: 3px;
                    background: #fcfbfb;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
                    /*border: 1px solid #ddd;*/
                }

                .accordion1 li:hover h2 {
                    color: white;
                    background-image: url("./compo_images/arrow_exp_n.gif");
                    background: url('compo_images/gradient_v_orange.gif') repeat-x;
                }

            .accord > li {
                padding: 0;
                list-style-type: none;
            }

                .accord > li > a {
                    text-decoration: none;
                    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    font-size: 12px;
                    padding-left: 12px;
                    color: #5f5c5c;
                    background: url("./compo_images/arrow_pointer_se.gif") 0.002em no-repeat;
                }

                .accord > li > ul > li > a {
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: #5f5c5c;
                    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    font-size: 11px;
                    background: url("./compo_images/arrow_dirmini_orange_e.gif") 0.35em no-repeat;
                    padding-left: 17px;
                }

                .accord > li > ul {
                    list-style-type: none;
                    text-align: left;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 1px;
                }

            .accord {
                text-decoration: none;
                padding-left: 5px;
            }

                .accord > li > a:hover {
                    color: #f8b106;
                }

                .accord > li > ul > li > a:hover {
                    color: #f8b106;
                }

            .accordion1 > li > h2.active {
                color: white;
                background: url('compo_images/gradient_v_orange.gif') repeat-x;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrap">

            <ul class="accordion1">
                <li>
                    <h2 id="first">CMT</h2>
                    <div class="content">
                        <ul class="accord">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">main link1</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link Four</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link Five</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="#">main link2</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link Four</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link Five</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2 id="fois"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:black;">FOIS</a></h2>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2>ASP</h2>
                    <div class="content">
                        <ul>

                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2>PTT</h2>
                    <div class="content">
                        content PTT
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- wrap -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

accord file

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.accord li').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideDown()
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideUp()
    }).find('ul').hide()

    var $lis = $('.accordion1 > li'), $contents = $lis.children('.content').hide();
    var $h2s = $lis.children('h2').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this), $t = $this.next();
        $contents.not($t).stop(true, true).slideUp();
        $this.toggleClass('active', !$t.is(':visible'));
        $t.slideToggle();
        $h2s.not(this).removeClass('active');
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `color: black;` using `inline` CSS, which will be only overridden if you use `!important` in your stylesheet.

Secondly you need to target `a` element and not `h2` because `a` will not inherit the parent elements color unless you specify something like `a {color: inherit;}` which will make all the `a` elements in your document `inherit` parent color, or to be specific you can use `.accordion1 li h2 a {color: inherit;}`, if you use this selector, than you don't have to target `a` else you need to as I've shared below..

```
.accordion1 li:hover h2 a {
    color: white !important;
    background-image: url("./compo_images/arrow_exp_n.gif");
    background: url('compo_images/gradient_v_orange.gif') repeat-x;
}
```

I would suggest you to remove the inline style instead, and you won't have to use the `!important` anymore.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YykGV/)

Comment: ok this works now i have another problem when this tab is active the text of the link should be changed to white.i have edit the post and include the accord.js file

Comment: @user2841408 you should perhaps ask another question if this is JS related :)

Answer (score 2):

Because  it's wrapped in `<a></a>` tag and the others are not wrapped in `<a>`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/E2LAG/)

```
<li>
   <h2 id="fois">FOIS</h2> // Your <h2> is wrapped in <a></a> here
</li>
```

Comment: yes but i want when i mouse over the fois its text changes to white

Comment: Yes because you have provided the styles for the same and your question says that it's not changing the color. So what is you are trying to achieve?

Comment: when i mouse over the fois header the text of the fois remains black instead of white.i want it white in color

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<h2 id="fois"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:black;">FOIS</a></h2>
```

To

```
<h2 id="fois"><a href="#">FOIS</a></h2>
```

And change

```
.accordion1 li:hover h2 {
```

To

```
.accordion1 li:hover h2,
.accordion1 li:hover h2 a {
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that your problem is with the inline style on the anchor element. This has a higher specificity than any style in a style sheet so should be used with moderation.

If you remove

```
color:black
```

from the anchor, and add:

```
color:black
```

to:

```
.accordion1 h2
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Add Below class in your style

```
 #fois a:hover{
     color: white !important;
    }
```

Comment: its only when i mouse over the link,but i want when i mouse hover the header the color  of text changes to white