# active tab text color should change to white

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my problem is when the tab fois tab is active the color of the header should change to orange and the color of the text should change to white(instead of orange i m using the orange image)...........

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <!--  <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="accord.js"></script>
    <style>
        .wrap {
            margin-left: 0px;
            margin-top: 0px;
            width: 100px;
        }

        .accordion1 {
            width: 178px;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            list-style: none;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
        }

            .accordion1 h2 {
                font-size: 12px;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                margin: 0px;
                text-decoration: none;
                padding: .25em .25em .25em 2em;
                color: #333;
                background: url('compo_images/gradient_v_gray.gif') repeat-x;
                background: url("./compo_images/arrow_exp_s.gif") 1em .75em no-repeat;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

                .accordion1 h2:hover {
                    background: url('compo_images/gradient_v_orange.gif') repeat-x;
                    color: white;
                }

            .accordion1 li div.content {
                padding: 3px;
                background: #fcfbfb;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
                /*border: 1px solid #ddd;*/
            }

            .accordion1 li:hover h2 {
                color: white !important;
                background-image: url("./compo_images/arrow_exp_n.gif");
                background: url('compo_images/gradient_v_orange.gif') repeat-x;
            }

                .accordion1 li:hover h2 a {
                    color: white !important;
                }

            .accordion1 li > h2:active a {
                color: white;
            }

        .accord > li {
            padding: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
        }

            .accord > li > a {
                text-decoration: none;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 12px;
                padding-left: 12px;
                color: #5f5c5c;
                background: url("./compo_images/arrow_pointer_se.gif") 0.002em no-repeat;
            }

            .accord > li > ul > li > a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #5f5c5c;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 11px;
                background: url("./compo_images/arrow_dirmini_orange_e.gif") 0.35em no-repeat;
                padding-left: 17px;
            }

            .accord > li > ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                text-align: left;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 1px;
            }

        .accord {
            text-decoration: none;
            padding-left: 5px;
        }

            .accord > li > a:hover {
                color: #f8b106;
            }

            .accord > li > ul > li > a:hover {
                color: #f8b106;
            }

        .accordion1 > li > h2.active {
            color: white;
            background: url('compo_images/gradient_v_orange.gif') repeat-x;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrap">

        <ul class="accordion1">
            <li>
                <h2 id="first">CMT</h2>
                <div class="content">
                    <ul class="accord">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">main link1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Four</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Five</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">main link2</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Four</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Five</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;">FOIS</a></h2>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>ASP</h2>
                <div class="content">
                    <ul>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>PTT</h2>
                <div class="content">
                    content PTT
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- wrap -->
</body>
</html>
```

accord file

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.accord li').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideDown()
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideUp()
    }).find('ul').hide()

    var $lis = $('.accordion1 > li'), $contents = $lis.children('.content').hide();
    var $h2s = $lis.children('h2').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this), $t = $this.next();
        $contents.not($t).stop(true, true).slideUp();
        $this.toggleClass('active', !$t.is(':visible'));
        $t.slideToggle();
        $h2s.not(this).removeClass('active');
    })
})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [change the color of the particular header on mouse over](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267250/change-the-color-of-the-particular-header-on-mouse-over)

Comment: @LinkinTED the question that i asked previous is related to mouse over but this question is  related to active tab in jquery

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adambotley/6YnRW/)

You only need css to alter the styling.

```
.accordion1 li:hover{
            background-color: orange;
            color: white;
        }
```

Comment: not working i need when the fois tab is active its text color changes to white.

Comment: I don't understand what you're requesting, sorry