# text color changes to white during a active tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My problem is when the fois tab is active its color is not changing to white.i want when any tab is active the text color changes to white and background changes to orange.
below is fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/TfQU8/

```
<div class="wrap">

        <ul class="accordion1">
            <li>
                <h2 id="first">CMT</h2>
                <div class="content">
                    <ul class="accord">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">main link1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Four</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Five</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">main link2</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Four</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link Five</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2><a href="#">FOIS</a></h2>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>ASP</h2>
                <div class="content">
                    <ul>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>PTT</h2>
                <div class="content">
                    content PTT
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

css

```
.wrap {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100px;
}

.accordion1 {
    width: 178px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

    .accordion1 h2 {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin: 0px;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: .25em .25em .25em 2em;
        color: #333;
        background: url('compo_images/gradient_v_gray.gif') repeat-x;
        background: url("./compo_images/arrow_exp_s.gif") 1em .75em no-repeat;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

        .accordion1 h2:hover {
            background: url('compo_images/gradient_v_orange.gif') repeat-x;
            color: white;
        }

    .accordion1 li h2 a {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .accordion1 li div.content {
        padding: 3px;
        background: #fcfbfb;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        /*border: 1px solid #ddd;*/
    }

    .accordion1 li:hover h2 {
        color: white !important;
        background-image: url("./compo_images/arrow_exp_n.gif");
        background:orange;
    }

        .accordion1 li:hover h2 a {
            color: white !important;
        }

.accord > li {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

    .accord > li > a {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding-left: 12px;
        color: #5f5c5c;
        background: url("./compo_images/arrow_pointer_se.gif") 0.002em no-repeat;
    }

    .accord > li > ul > li > a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #5f5c5c;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        background: url("./compo_images/arrow_dirmini_orange_e.gif") 0.35em no-repeat;
        padding-left: 17px;
    }

    .accord > li > ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        text-align: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 1px;
    }

.accord {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

    .accord > li > a:hover {
        color: #f8b106;
    }

    .accord > li > ul > li > a:hover {
        color: #f8b106;
    }

.accordion1 > li > h2.active {
    color: white;
    background: orange;
}
```

accord

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.accord li').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideDown()
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideUp()
    }).find('ul').hide()

    var $lis = $('.accordion1 > li'), $contents = $lis.children('.content').hide();
    var $h2s = $lis.children('h2').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this), $t = $this.next();
        $contents.not($t).stop(true, true).slideUp();
        $this.toggleClass('active', !$t.is(':visible'));
        $t.slideToggle();
        $h2s.not(this).removeClass('active');
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

So you come back again, what you will need is this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TfQU8/1/)

```
.accordion1 > li > h2.active, .accordion1 > li > h2.active a {
    color: white;
    background: orange;
}
```

Explanation:

You had this selector `.accordion1 > li > h2.active` which targets `h2` element having a class `.active` and as I explained you yesterday over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19267334/1542290), your `a` element won't inherit the color unless you specify to inherit, so your FOIS is wrapped using `a` so inorder to target that, I've added another selector in your CSS.

---

On the other hand, you can also use the selector with the `color` set to `inherit`

```
.accordion1 > li > h2.active a {
    color: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want just use css:you should use 
 `a:link,a:visited,a:hover,a:active`  to change your css,you can write css code for any of them